# Stretch other divs to width of the widest one

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to build a page which has header, footer and a simple form. I need the form elements to have the same width as submit button but I can't set the width statically as the page needs to be multilingual and therefore I don't know what size will the button have.

Is there any way how to let the width of button to be dynamic and stretch other divs (inputs) to the same width? I guess I could use Javascript but I was wondering if this could be solved CSS only.

I also need the form to be centered and I'm using Bootstrap (if that helps).

[image]

Comment: If you gave everything a `.width` class and applied it to all the elements and just style `.width` with `width:` then they would all be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is, take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/7y3ska30/
Basically assign this styles for the input(s)

```
input{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

If you use bootstrap for the submit use `.btn .btn-block` and for the input use `.col-md-12`.

Comment: Can we see some code to understand better the problem?

Comment: I think you can solve the problem using bootstrap class without adding other css code.